# HTML <input> tag working with an invalid "value"

Tags: html, post, forms, html-input

I saw an HTML code on a webpage as

```
<input type="test" name=rat value=0.5  size="4" maxlength="4">
```

It is creating a valid text box on the webpage as [image: Snapshot from the webpage]

I verified that **test** is not a valid value for the **type** attribute. However, while posting the POST response for the form which contains this input, the **rat** value is correctly passed. I am using chrome on windows.
Any inputs on how the error correction is happening. I would have expected the code to have failed because of invalid value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "test" is not a valid type it is being ignored and falls back to the default type which is "text". The same thing happens when you do not supply any type attribute at all.

Answer (score 1):

As Ricky points out, the behavior of the browser when faced with an invalid type attribute vale, is to switch to the default type which is text as explained in the link below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input